# How to serialize multiple images(as in url) of an object in DRF?

Tags: json, django, api, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a Image model related to Item model via ForeignKey, but the API endpoint of this resource only shows the images's name instead of image's url. (I have a single imagefiled in Item model, which can be shown as url/uri). So, how to serialize the data in order to get all the media urls for the images.

Models :

```
class Item(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    img = models.ImageField()
```

```
class ItemDetailImg(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Serializers:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ("id",
                  "title",
                  ...
                  "images"
                  )
```

one API response:

```
{
        "id": 16,
        "title": "Venice",

        ...

        "img": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/roman-kraft-g_gwdpsCVAY-unsplash.jpg",

        "images": [
            7,
            8
        ]
    }
```

I expect this kind of api response

```
{
        "id": 16,
        "title": "Venice",

        ...

        "img": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/roman-kraft-g_gwdpsCVAY-unsplash.jpg",

        "images": [
            "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image1.jpg",
            "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image2.jpg"
        ]
    }
```

Thank you, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: show us a part from where you got this data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually want a related field have a look in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/), but it is unclear how you compute image's url, so I'll propose a solution below

```
class ItemDetailImg(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField()

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        return "{0}{1}".format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image.url)
```

and now in your serializer add a slug related field like below

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    imges = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field="image_url")
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ("id",
                  "title",
                  ...
                  "images"
                  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the right way to do. it works.